# How to handle the removal of database encryption in the next version of iOS application?

Tags: ios, swift, upgrade, sqlite.swift

In iOS app version 1, I am storing each and every data in table in encrypted form. But In iOS app version 2, I have removed the encryption of those data in each and every table. During app upgrade from version 1 to version 2, since the older version has encrypted data, the new version is not able to understand the data fetched. How should I go about this?

iOS application - supporting till OS 12.

Comment: how much data you currently have in the older version?

Comment: No changes in the table structure. Same set of tables. Data depends on the users who are using the application right?

Answer (score 0):

So you have not decrypted the data during the migrating from version 1 to version 2.  Have you stored the key to encrypt/decrypt in keychain or do you have access to the key to decrypt the info in version 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you store data within app database after encryptions then don’t need to worry. Nothing will happen with the older version of your app if you upload next version. Only the changes will not reflect directly to the previous version of your app you have to forcefully update an app version from the user.

You can show  the alert massage when user open the application like “new version is available please checked” and redirect to the App store.

Answer (score 0):

There can be two options and might one of them will help you.

**Option : 1**

- You can ask end-user to make force update and update the new version of an existing installed app.

**Option : 2**

- If you don’t want users to loose there existing data what you need to check is…
- With the new version of the app, you need to check whether old data exist in the application or not. 
  If YES, you can update them by making it decrepit and if the answer is NO there you can make the user access your application further.

*With this approach make sure users are having a good experience and don’t get annoyed if you perform background tasks while updating the existing data to decrypted one.*

Hope the above explanation can assist you.